# ARM Templates: depends on -- do you refer to the linked "Microsoft.Resources/deployments" or the resources created within it?

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I have a parent ARM Template (eg: myapp.assembly.json) that invokes linked child ARM Templates (web.serverFarm.json, web.site.json, etc.)

Currently I have defined the relationship between linked child templates by putting `dependsOn`

- in the parent ARM template
- referencing the name of the linked `Microsoft.Resources/deployments` (and not the names of resources created *within* the linked resource template).

I was expecting:

- any `Microsoft.Resources/deployments` that had a `dependsOn` defined for another `Microsoft.Resources/deployments` would wait till all those resources are created.

What I think I am observing is:

- the first time the ARM template is run, it reports that the deployment fails ...looking for dependencies...
- but continues working...so can't redeploy immediately...
- the second time, the resources are built, and the deployment completes.

It's entirely possible I'm missing a `dependsOn` -- although I've really looked and don't think so -- or the `dependsOn` is not being honored in the way I would have expected.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: show the template

Comment: You're correct in that you dependsOn the deployment resource... the dependsOn property is *only* for resources defined in the same template.  The behavior you're seeing is strongly indicative of missing a dependsOn somewhere...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agh!
Thank you @ 4c74356b41 and @bmoore-msft ... you were absolutely correct (it was right in front of my nose for an embarrassing amount of days :-( )

I must have copy/pasted from the child resource template to the parent assembly template.

```
"webSiteConfigAppSettingsApplicationInsightsInstrumentationKey": {
  // FIX: Rely on the template instead of direct:"value": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/components', variables('insights').components.resourceName), '2015-05-01').InstrumentationKey]"
  "value": "[reference(variables('insights').components.armTemplateId).outputs.instrumentationKey.value]"
}
```

ie:
I needed to reference the template and it's output. 
Not the resource created *within* the template...which the parent template could not see.

All works smooth as butter now.